# Defining multiple names for the same getter/setter function in a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, class

How can I assign multiple names to the same getter/setter function inside a JS class? I know I can just do something like this:

```
class Example
{
    static #privateVar = 0;

    static get name(){ /* code and stuff */ return this.#privateVar; }
    static get anotherName(){ /* code and stuff */ return this.#privateVar; }

    static set name(value){ /* validating input values or something here */ this.#privateVar = value; }
    static set anotherName(value){ /* validating input values or something here */ this.#privateVar = value; }
}
```

but is there a simple way to give the same function multiple names without copying the code? I know I don't need different functions, but if someone else is using the class (or I just forget) and wants to use a different name for the function (i.e, different abbreviations, grey/gray, etc.), it would be convenient.

Comment: Why is everything `static` in that class?

Comment: No reason specific to the question - the original class from my question had everything static so I just copied it over

Comment: I recommend not to use a `class` for that then, but rather a simple object literal.

Comment: @Bergi fair point, but I needed some private functions and variables which to my knowledge you can't have with objects

Comment: Just place them in the module (or IIFE) scope next to the exported (or returned) object. They don't need to be part of the object. Alternatively, use symbols or the leading underscore in the name which by convention are also private, if your use case allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and `Object.defineProperty` to copy the accessors:

```
class Example {
    static #privateVar = 0;

    static get name(){ /* code and stuff */ return this.#privateVar; }
    static set name(value){ /* validating input values or something here */ this.#privateVar = value; }

    static {
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'anotherName', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'name'));
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for both the getter and the setter at once, very useful thanks

Comment: Is there a way to put this code inside or wrap one of the name() functions and replace `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, 'name')` with just `this` or something? That way I can change the name of the original function and it won't break. Also, is there an easy way to define multiple alternate names without having to copy that line multiple times?

Comment: No, you cannot put it inside the `name` functions, but you can of course do `const descriptor = {get() { … }, set() { … }}; Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', descriptor); Object.defineProperty(this, 'anotherName', descriptor);`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return the value from the other function:

```js
static get anotherName() {
  return this.name;
}
```

and

```js
static set anotherName(value) {
  this.name = value;
}
```

Comment: Simple and works great, thanks